# OnCollisionEnter doesn't work: changing wheelcollider's sideway friction stiffness

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Iam trying to change a value in a component but it doesn't work, here is my code:

I've tried to initialize the variables outside the method but it gives me an error, because I initialized the wheel colliders (FDW,FPW,BDW,BPW) first

```
 private void Slip()
{
    //FPW, FDW, BPW, and BDW are all wheel colliders
    float stiffness1 = FPW.sidewaysFriction.stiffness;
    float stiffness2 = FDW.sidewaysFriction.stiffness;
    float stiffness3 = BPW.sidewaysFriction.stiffness;
    float stiffness4 = BDW.sidewaysFriction.stiffness;

    stiffness1 = 5;
    stiffness2 = 5;
    stiffness3 = 5;
    stiffness4 = 5;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    Slip();
}
```

Comment: where is your error code ?

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work

Comment: if you meant what was the error mentioned in the question, it is "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property"

Comment: that problem possible in your field declare , Can you paste it ?

Comment: @TimChang like what I said, I removed the variables from the declaration field into the `Slip();` function and initialized them there. But anyways the new version of code without the "stiffness variables" is in the comment below

Comment: `private float m_horizontal;
    private float m_vertical;
    private float m_currentSteerAngle;

    // BDW, BPW, etc... are wheel locations relative to the seats. For example FPW means Front Passenger Wheel and FDW means Front Driver Wheel.
    public WheelCollider BDW, BPW;
    public WheelCollider FDW, FPW;
    public Transform BDT, BPT;
    public Transform FDT, FPT;
    public float maxSteerAngle = 30;
    public float torque = 50;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WheelFrictionCurve` is a struct, so if you want to change its properties, you need to:

```
var curve = FPW.sidewaysFriction;
curve.stiffness = 5;
FPW.sidewaysFriction = curve;
```

Comment: this comment is probably getting removed and it is a bit cheesy, but I wanna thank you for what you did... it may seem simple because I am a noob in c# but I've been thinking about this problem for about a week now and it was really draining ... you are a life saver.